# SQL Return only where more than one join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Not sure how to ask this as I'm a bit of a database noob,

What I want to do is the following.

```
table tb_Company
table tb_Division
```

I want to return companies that have more than one division and I don't know how to do the where clause.

```
SELECT   dbo.tb_Company.CompanyID, dbo.tb_Company.CompanyName, 
dbo.tb_Division.DivisionName FROM dbo.tb_Company INNER JOIN dbo.tb_Division ON 
dbo.tb_Company.CompanyID = dbo.tb_Division.DivisionCompanyID
```

Any help or links much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need another `JOIN` where you only return companies having more than one division by using a `GROUP BY`and a `HAVING`clause.

You can read up on grouping [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

> Groups a selected set of rows into a
>   set of summary rows by the values of
>   one or morecolumns or expressions. One
>   row is returned for each group.
>   Aggregate functions in the SELECT
>   clause  list provide
>   information about each group instead
>   of individual rows.

```
SELECT   dbo.tb_Company.CompanyID
        , dbo.tb_Company.CompanyName
        , dbo.tb_Division.DivisionName 
FROM    dbo.tb_Company 
        INNER JOIN dbo.tb_Division ON dbo.tb_Company.CompanyID = dbo.tb_Division.DivisionCompanyID
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  DivisionCompanyID
          FROM    dbo.tb_Division
          GROUP BY
                  DivisionCompanyID
          HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) d ON d.DivisionCompanyID = dbo.tb_Company.CompanyID
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? If what is posted is wrong, you should say so and help OP solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
WITH COUNTED AS
(
  SELECT C.CompanyID, C.CompanyName, D.DivisionName,
         COUNT() OVER(PARTITION BY C.CompanyID) AS Cnt
  FROM dbo.tb_Company C
  INNER JOIN dbo.tb_Division D ON C.CompanyID = D.DivisionCompanyID
)
SELECT *
FROM COUNTED
WHERE Cnt > 1
```

With the other solutions (that join onto `Division` table twice), a single company/division can be returned under a heavy insert load.

If a row is inserted into the `Division` table between the time the first join occurs and the time the second join (with the `group by`/`having`) is evaluated, the first `Division` join will return a single row. However, the second one will return a count of 2.

Comment: tbh i can't see this particular query (for companies and divisions) ever being under a heavy insert load...

Answer (score 0):

another alternative...

```
SELECT c.CompanyId, c.CompanyName, d.DivisionName
FROM tbl_Company c
INNER JOIN tbl_Division d ON c.CompanyId=d.DivisionCompanyId
GROUP BY c.CompanyId, c.CompanyName, d.DivisionName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Will this return any rows at all (when there are no duplicate records per company in Division table)?

Comment: @Chris Bednarski: the query will return all companies that have more than 1 department (as per the requirement in your post). If there is one department or less in a company, the company will not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
SELECT dbo.tb_Company.CompanyID,
       dbo.tb_Company.CompanyName, 
    FROM dbo.tb_Company
    WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM dbo.tb_Division
               WHERE dbo.tb_Company.CompanyID =
                          dbo.tb_Division.DivisionCompanyID) > 1;
```